# Get location as latitude and longitude from Geography in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: t-sql, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have saved latitudes and longitudes for my points as Geography typed. I created custom api and I am able to retrieve points from closest by this code:

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {
    var lat = request.query.latitude.replace(",",".");
    var lng = request.query.longitude.replace(",",".");
    var limit = +request.query.limit;
    if (!limit) limit = 20;
    console.log('Filtr: lat - %s, lng - %s, limit - %s', lat, lng, limit);
    var mssql = request.service.mssql;
    var queryString = "SELECT TOP (?) id, title, description, category, city, street, price, startdate, enddate, location.Lat latitude, location.Long longitude, location.STDistance(geography::Point(?, ?, 4326)) AS distance FROM Action ORDER BY distance"
    mssql.query(queryString, [limit, lat, lng], {
        success: function(results) {
            request.respond(statusCodes.OK, results);
        }
    });
};
```

But I want to retrieve all points and I can't figure out how to do it. Now when I have just in script operation read:

```
function read(query, user, request) {
    request.execute();
}
```

I get this in my object:

```
"location":{
"0":230,
"1":16,
"2":0,
"3":0,
"4":1,
"5":12,
"6":67,
"7":203,
"8":186,
"9":127,
"10":44,
"11":190,
"12":72,
"13":64,
"14":70,
"15":64,
"16":133,
"17":35,
"18":72,
"19":169,
"20":48,
"21":64,
"length":22
},
```

I was trying to modified sql script from custom api to apply to read operation but I don't know how to change query in read operation script. I was trying to work with success after executing request but It's too late. Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution to my problem:

```
function read(query, user, request) {
  var queryString = "SELECT id, title, description, category, city, street, price, startdate, enddate, location.Lat latitude, location.Long longitude FROM Action";   
  mssql.query(queryString, { 
                success: function(results) { 
                     request.respond(statusCodes.OK, results); 
                } 
          }); 
}
```

I tried this as first option before I asked the question but I tried it with this line:

```
var mssql = request.service.mssql;
```

But then I found example without this line and still with mssql object and it's working.

Comment: You're right. `mssql` is a global variable in table scripts, but there are no globals in custom APIs, so you need to access those via the `request.service` object.